# Scripting. Multiple threads vs multiple instances

Tags: python, ruby, multithreading, multiprocessing

I need to write a script (python/ruby) that will do some work (database transactions, calculations) based on different AMQP requests. In order to handle all the requests as fast as possible I intend to either run multiple instances of that python script (each would listen to the same queue and handle different requests) or use multithreading to achieve the same running only 1 script instance.

Which way is better? What are the cons and pros?

Edit: I do not need any ipc or thread communication. Each request is handled in 1 thread and doesnt need to know anything about other threads/processes

Comment: Not really. That question is strictly about python and implementation.

Comment: I feel like you're asking which you should use, which indicates you need more knowledge on their limitations. I use threads when I have enough CPU time (so a single process is fine), which is the common case when waiting for network (scraping). If, however, I have a lot of data to process very quickly and the cpu is constantly at 100%, I may consider processes.